# Make a code with number prefix and other string prefix in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, prefix

I have to make a format for transaction number and the format example is a `BKK-202009-00001`. The number 00001 that will auto increment.I've tried but not getting the expected output.

CODING

```
public function createBefore($model, $arrayData, $metaData, $id=null) 
{
    //$arrayData["no_draft"] = $this->custom_getdraftid(null);
    $prefix = 'BBK';
  
    if ($arrayData['payment_type']=='CASH') {
        $prefix='BKK';
    } elseif ($arrayData['payment_type']=='GIRO') {
        $prefix='BGK';
    }
    ff($prefix);
    $no_transaction = \DB::table('acc_tra_cash_bank_expenses_header')
    ->selectRaw(" '$prefix' || '-' ||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM')||'-'||RIGHT('0000'||(
                            RIGHT( (SELECT no_transaction FROM acc_tra_cash_bank_expenses_header WHERE no_transaction LIKE '$prefix'||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM')||'%'
                                        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),5)::INTEGER+1)::TEXT,5) AS no_transaction")->first();
    ff($no_transaction->no_transaction);
    if (!$no_transaction) {
        $bulantanggal = date('Ym');
        $no_transaction->no_transaction = "$prefix-$bulantanggal-00001";
    }
    
    $newModel = $model;
    $newArrayData  = array_merge($arrayData, [
       'no_draft'=> $this->custom_getdraftid(null),
        'no_transaction' => $no_transaction->no_transaction
    ]);
    return [
        "model"  => $newModel,
        "data"   => $newArrayData,
    ];
}
```

Comment: `00001`, is it coming from anywhere like `id` or you have to increment it yourself??

Comment: increment it not from anywhere

Comment: how many zeroes you want to prefix?? like if the number is 1000 or 99 or 99999 what will be the expected output??

Comment: 00001 four zero if number 1000 01000

Comment: You say you aren't getting the expected output, but you didn't share what you did get. It is very helpful to share with us what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need a format like `BKK-202009-00001` with incrementing number. A solution would be like

```
$string = 'BKK-202009-00001'; //the last entry from the database
$number = last(explode("-",$string)); //explode the string to get the number part, last is a laravel helper
$new = str_pad(intval($number) + 1, 5, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); //increment the number by 1 and pad with 0 in left.

$no_transaction->no_transaction = $prefix.'-'.$bulantanggal.'-'.$new; //concat string and number to generate the desired output
```

Comment: i got error explode() expects parameter 2 to be string object given

Comment: what have you passed in  place of `$string` in explode?? you have to pass an object property not the object itself.

Comment: a query builder 
$no_transaction = \DB::table('acc_tra_cash_bank_expenses_header')
          ->selectRaw(" '$prefix' || '-' ||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM')||'-'||RIGHT('0000'||(
        RIGHT( (SELECT no_transaction FROM acc_tra_cash_bank_expenses_header WHERE no_transaction LIKE '$prefix'||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMM')||'%'
           ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1),5)::INTEGER+1)::TEXT,5) AS no_transaction")->first();

Comment: pass like `$no_transaction->no_transaction`

Comment: can you show me what is `$no_transaction->no_transaction`?? and what's the current generated output??

Comment: No transaction contains a builder query like I wrote my question above can be seen part of the coding

Comment: not that builder i want to know. what's the output?? if you `dd($no_transaction->no_transaction)` what do you get??

Comment: then the problem is in your query. i have showed you how to generate the transaction number. you have to just fetch the previous one from the db and use that to make the new one.

Comment: and why have you written a complex query like that?? what are you trying to achieve here??